# What's the chemical reaction between NaOCl and Brilliant Blue dye?

Tags: organic-chemistry, organic-oxidation

Based on my research NaOCl dissociates into Na+ and OCl-. Looking at the photo, how does the OCl- ion and the brilliant blue dye structure end up as the product? How does the OH attach itself to the carbon group and what happens to the Cl- afterwards? I'm pretty sure since the C group has a double bond it needs to be broken by an addition reaction but I'm not sure how.

[image: Brilliant Blue CFC structure and OCl- reacting together]

Comment: I don't trust this product structure, to begin with. What's with that trivalent carbon to the right?

Comment: I doubt the reaction occurs as written. The transformation from left to right is not due to the $\ce{OCl^-}$ ion. No. It is due to the addition of $\ce{H2O}$ and this addition is improbable because the quinonic ring would loose its aromaticity in the reaction. I would rather think the hypochlorite ion acts on one of  the Nitrogen atoms.

Comment: I think you guys are right. It seems strange that the Cl- isn't at all involved in the reaction. This is the source I found the mechanism from if it helps: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1dI9CoBMX14Rk9j4m0atFnw-axXZnV_hm/view?usp=sharing

Comment: If you read the reference, they say that the product of the reaction is "not perfectly known". And indeed the formula of the product has no influence on the exercise. The only thing to know is the fact that bleach destroys the dye. And measuring its absorbance decay allows you to know the rate law of this reaction. This is the only important.information.